# having trouble with separating the string and search word order with my search bar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

This is my search bar code that I was able to write. However I have been trying to find a solution to how I can search for something no matter the order of the word by splitting the string.

For example, when searching for `the red car` instead of me writing `the red car` to be able to find it, I can search `red the car`, `car the red` and so on.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
  });
  
  $('#search').keyup(function() {
    $('#result').show();
    $('#state').val('');
    var searchField = $('#search').val();
    var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");

    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
      var found = false;
      $('#result').html('');
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        if (value.name.search(expression) != -1) {
          found = true;
          $('#result').append('<a href="' + value.link + '" <li class="list-group-item">  ' + value.name + ' </li></a>');
        }
      });

      if (!found) {
        $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item not-found">Item not found!</li>');
      }
    });

    if (!$(this).val().length) 
      $('#result').hide();
  });
});
```

I have tried to put `split(' ')` on `var searchField = $('#search').val().split(' ')`, but nothing happened.

I have been stuck on this for a while, so this is my last hope. I did a bunch of research on it, and I couldn't find anything

Comment: Hi. `var searchField = $('#search').val().split(' ')` `searchField.some((v) => targetList.includes(v))`

try smth like this. Common thing is splitting and looping with the `includes` method. And of course make sure there is data in your variable after splitting or not and how are they looks like. Maybe it needs to trim

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#search').on('keyup', function () {
      var searchField = $(this).val();

      $('#result').html('');
//the ajax response sample
      var data = [{
        name: "the car red",
        link: "a"
      },
      {
        name: "the red car",
        link: "b"
      },
      {
        name: "red the car",
        link: "c"
      },
      {
        name: "yellow the car",
        link: "d"
      },
      {
        name: "car the orange",
        link: "e"
      }
      ];
      var found = false;

      var words = searchField.match(/\b\w+\b/g);
      var foundObjects = data.filter(function (obj) {
        return words.every(function (word) {
          return Object.values(obj).some(function (value) {
            return value.toLowerCase().indexOf(word) !== -1;
          });
        });
      });

      if (foundObjects.length > 0) {
        $.each(foundObjects, function (key, value) {
          $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item"><a href="' + value.link + '" <li class="list-group-item">  ' + value.name + ' </li></a></li>');
        });
      } else {
        $('#result').html('<li class="list-group-item not-found">Item not found!</li>');
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search...">
<ul id="result">
</ul>
```